# External HDD works on Windows and Mac, but not detected/showing up in Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, hard-drive, external-hdd

Recently switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu in my PC. So, I'm new to Ubuntu OS.

I have a 1 TB external HDD that has been formatted in Windows 7. That HDD detected in Windows & Mac OS. So, we can able to transfer the files from HDD to Laptop and Laptop to HDD in both Windows and Mac OS. But, Ubuntu won't detect this external hard drive. I am confused why it didn't show up in ubuntu. Gparted also not showing this external HDD.

Unable to format partition in ubuntu too. Everything is disabled except edit mount option. Attached screenshot from my PC Disks.

[image]